# How to select records from one table missing in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Tables employee master Table and Timesheet Table.

Employee Table Structure :

```
+------------+---------+
| emp_number | empname |
+------------+---------+
|          2 | Jagdish |
|          3 | Sulata  |
|          4 | Prasad  |
|          5 | Vijay   |
|          6 | Armin   |
+------------+---------+
```

And Timesheet Table Structure :

```
+------------+--------+------------+------------+
| emp_number | status | startDate  | EndDate    |
+------------+--------+------------+------------+
|          2 | 0      | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07 |
|          3 | 1      | 2016-02-01 | 2016-02-06 |
|          4 | 40     | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07 |
|          9 | 0      | 2016-01-06 | 2016-01-12 |
|         10 | 4      | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-08 |
+------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Can we write a query to fetch records for all employees using group by week?
Please Guide me on that. Thank You.

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: You can join two tables on emp_number column using LEFT JOIN. In where clause if you select emp_number is NULL condition then you will get missing rows

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags. Feel free to add one of them back.

Comment: @Madhura,  `DATE()` function does not exists in all those dbms products. Which one are you using? (Remove the tags for products not involved.)

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server, MySQL, MariaDB and Informatica with this query? Somehow, I find that hard to believe. Please remove *all* irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Timesheet WHERE Employee.emp_number = Timesheet 
.emp_number AND Status IN (0,40))
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code as per your given question

```
select employee.* 
from employee
where employee.emp_number not in (select emp_number from timesheet)
and timesheet.status in (0,40) and timesheet.enddate between '2016-01-01'
and '2016-01-07'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the right code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Timesheet INNER JOIN Employee ON Timesheet.emp_number=Employee.emp_number
WHERE (Employee.status = 0 OR Employee.status = 40) 
  AND (Timesheet.startDate = '2016-01-01' AND Timesheet.EndDate = '2016-01-07')
```

You might need to change the dates between the semi-colons depending on what datatype startDate and EndDate are,

Eg: '2016-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: No its not working. I think left join will work instead of inner join. But i an not getting where to add the extra status and date conditions.

Answer (score 0):

-- Try this code. It's faster

```
WITH cte_timesheet AS (
  select employee_id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN status IN (0,40) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) include_status
     from em_timesheet
     where start_date = '2016-12-05'
       AND end_date = '2016-12-11'
    GROUP BY employee_id
)
SELECT emp_number,
       empname
  FROM em_employee e
    LEFT JOIN cte_timesheet t ON t.employee_id = e.emp_number
  WHERE t.employee_id IS NULL
     OR t.include_status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.its very simple

```
select * from #emp E
LEFT JOIN #TimeSheet T ON t.emp_nbr=e.emp_nbr
where startdate>='2016-01-01' and enddate<='2016-01-07'
and status_ in(0,40)
```